# SQL Syntax error using BETWEEN

Tags: sql

I have a table named ticket. I am trying to query between two dates, however; I keep getting a syntax error. Any help would appreciated as to what this syntax error may be.

```
SELECT date 
FROM ticket 
WHERE date BETWEEN YEAR(ticket.date)=2011 AND MONTH(ticket.date)=11 AND DAY(ticket.date)=06
                AND YEAR(ticket.date)=2011 AND MONTH(ticket.date)=11 AND DAY(ticket.date)=12
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=2011 AND MONTH(ticket.date)=11 AND DAY(ticket.date)=06 AND YEAR(ticket.date)=20' at line 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
date BETWEEN YEAR(ticket.date)=2011
```

doesn't make any sense. The syntax is

```
date BETWEEN start_range AND end_range
```

So presumably something like

```
date BETWEEN '2011-11-06' AND  '2011-11-12'
```

Or as you have a time component you should avoid use of `BETWEEN` at all and just use

```
date >= '2011-11-06' AND  date  < '2011-11-13'
```

Comment: I'm using the YEAR keyword because the date field has the date and time within it and from some of my past queries it filters out the information.

Comment: @MasterP - Just use `WHERE date >= '2011-11-06' AND  date  < '2011-11-13'`

Answer (score 1):

This is an incorrect `BETWEEN` clause:

```
BETWEEN YEAR(ticket.date)=2011
```

It should look like:

```
BETWEEN YEAR(ticket.date) AND 2011
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this we will do the trick:

```
"SELECT 
    date 
FROM 
    ticket 
WHERE 
    date BETWEEN '2011-11-06' AND 2011-11-12'"
```

You shouldn't use BETWEEN like you do. You are making a evaluation in a evaluation your (my)sql doesn't support that.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT date 
FROM ticket 
WHERE DAY(ticket.date) BETWEEN 6 AND 12
AND MONTH(ticket.date) = 11
AND YEAR(ticket.date) = 2011
```

Comment: That will be über-slow because MySQL cannot use an index on that query.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot list multiple values in `between` like that.

Rewrite the query to:

```
SELECT date  
FROM ticket  
WHERE date BETWEEN '2011-11-06' and '2011-11-12'
```